# Won't update taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm not really a Drupal guru, so any help it'd be awesome.

There's a taxonomy for every state (State Owner), which then allows me select the state when adding a new article.

However, I'm trying to add a National (NAT) to the list. I've added it to the taxonomy term list:
[image]

However, NAT won't show up on the State Owner field when adding a new article:

[image]

I can see the item on the DB too:
[image]

I've flushed the cache, even restarted the server... It just won't show up on the Add Article page (on the State Owner drop down).

Note that if I change the order of the states, it DOES change the order on the drop-down, so it's the correct taxonomy terms.

Any idea?

Comment: Try checking the widget type for that field, and that field settings under the Content type `Manage fields` and `Manage form display`. Maybe the widget is limiting the number of items to display.

Comment: On .`Manage Form Display` it says `Select List`.

On `Manage Field` it let me edit `State Onwer`, so if I go to  `Home => Administration => Structure  => Content types => Article =>  Manage fields => State owner`, although it says `There is data for this field in the database. The field settings can no longer be changed.`, I don't see any limitation in there?

Comment: What happens when you change `Select list` to `Checkboxes`? Do you see all the options? For me the Select list doesn't present as a drop-down, it's a small box with a scrollbar and all items are visible. Do you have any modules modifying how Select list works? Also can you try to change the theme to Bartik and see if it happens then.

Comment: 1-I changed it from `select list` to `checkboxes` but I still can't see `NAT`. 
2-I'm not sure they have a module to change the appearance of the `select list`.
3-Changed the theme to Bartik but nothing changed.

I noticed that they added these values via a `custom module`, with all the specifics of the project. I tried to uninstall the module, add NAT to the list, and install again but Drupal thinkins the module is still installed.

I also renamed one of the states to see what happens, and it indeed updated the name, so I fell like there's some kind of filtering by ID somewhere?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help out @prkos.

Comment: Based on everything you described, it doesn't seem like it's a bug in Drupal or some hidden behaviour or setting. It's most likely something to do with that custom module. Maybe the term data wasn't populated correctly. Do you see any difference in the database between the NAT and other records? Or even through the interface when you go to edit it? I think you better ask the programmers behind that custom code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else lands here looking for an answer, after going around in circles for many many hours, I found out the solution.

When I gave up and was about to recreate a core component in order to overcome this issue, the first thing to do was to delete this taxonomy term, however, Drupal flagged to me that it'd affect the Access Scheme / Taxonomy Main. Interesting, so I decided to Google it, I found out this text came from a component called `Workbench Access`, which among other things could manage a Scheme for Taxonomy. Looking into installed modules, I indeed had it installed. Bingo. However, I had no access to it (that's why I never actually found it).

The old developer (which I no longer had access to), made me "Admin" of the system as part of his handover. However, this component was hidden for all users, but his.

After copying my hashed password, replacing his with mine, and logging in as him, I could see this component on his user homepage, which was just a matter of disabling it for State Owner and voilá. Working like a charm.